# Failed to convert value of type '$Proxy55

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I have my spring batch program written all was working fine until I tried refactoring the name of beans and respective class names only then I started getting below exception

```
Error creating bean with name
'org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.xml.SimpleFlowFactoryBean#3':
Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#6aed4066' of type
[org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.StateTransition] while
setting bean property 'stateTransitions' with key [24]; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean
with name '(inner bean)#6aed4066': Cannot create inner bean '(inner 
bean)#7e1f1f61' of type
[org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState] while
setting constructor argument; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error
creating bean with name '(inner bean)#7e1f1f61': Unsatisfied dependency
expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type 
[org.springframework.batch.core.Step]: Could not convert constructor
argument value of type [$Proxy55] to...
```

So I am trying to understand what `$Proxy 55` is and why this exception is happening.

Comment: $Proxy is the name of a class that was created as a proxy for something in your configuration.  Spring will create proxies for interfaces, abstract classes, and probably other things.  Your problem is likely not cause by $Proxy 55.  $Proxy 55 appears to be a symptom of you problem.

Comment: Instead of using the technique of "me make many changers then am test" try resetting back to the working source, then making one change then testing.

Comment: @DwB Thank you for your input and suggestion will try few option and will revert in case i need more help

Comment: It turned to be an issue where same id was assigned to more than one spring bean gave unique name to each of them and issue got resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After examining id attribute of each spring bean in spring configuration file found that more than one spring bean had same id so after changing them to unique id the issue got resolved